# fail2ban not working

Tags: configuration, fail2ban

I have several services running on my Ubuntu 12.04 server and set up fail2ban, but it doesn't block the attacking IPs. SSH is running on port 22.

**jail.conf**

```
[DEFAULT]

bantime  = 600
maxretry = 3
banaction = iptables-multiport
action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
action_mw = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
              %(mta)s-whois[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
               %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s"]
action = %(action_)s


[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6
```

**regex check**

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/auth.log.1 /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf

Failregex
|- Regular expressions:
|  [1] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*(?:error: PAM: )?Authentication failure for
 .* from <HOST>\s*$
|  [2] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*(?:error: PAM: )?User not known to the unde
rlying authentication module for .* from <HOST>\s*$
|  [3] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*Failed (?:password|publickey) for .* from <
HOST>(?: port \d*)?(?: ssh\d*)?$
|  [4] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*ROOT LOGIN REFUSED.* FROM <HOST>\s*$
|  [5] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*[iI](?:llegal|nvalid) user .* from <HOST>\s
*$
|  [6] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*User .+ from <HOST> not allowed because not
 listed in AllowUsers$
|  [7] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*authentication failure; logname=\S* uid=\S*
 euid=\S* tty=\S* ruser=\S* rhost=<HOST>(?:\s+user=.*)?\s*$
|  [8] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*refused connect from \S+ \(<HOST>\)\s*$
|  [9] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*Address <HOST> .* POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT
!*\s*$
|  [10] ^\s*(?:\S+ )?(?:kernel: \[\d+\.\d+\] )?(?:@vserver_\S+ )?(?:(?:\[\d+\])?:\s+[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?|[\[\(]?sshd(?:\(\S+\))?[\]\)]?:?(?:\[\d+\])?:)?\s*User .+ from <HOST> not allowed because no
ne of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups\s*$
|
`- Number of matches:
   [1] 0 match(es)
   [2] 0 match(es)
   [3] 2810 match(es)
   [4] 0 match(es)
   [5] 2378 match(es)
   [6] 0 match(es)
   [7] 0 match(es)
   [8] 0 match(es)
   [9] 0 match(es)
   [10] 0 match(es)
```

[...]

```
Date template hits:
380718 hit(s): MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): WEEKDAY MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second Year
0 hit(s): WEEKDAY MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Year/Month/Day Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Day/Month/Year Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Day/Month/Year Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Day/MONTH/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Month/Day/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Year-Month-Day Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Year.Month.Day Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Day-MONTH-Year Hour:Minute:Second[.Millisecond]
0 hit(s): Day-Month-Year Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): TAI64N
0 hit(s): Epoch
0 hit(s): ISO 8601
0 hit(s): Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): <Month/Day/Year@Hour:Minute:Second>

Success, the total number of match is 5188
```

**auth.log**

```
Jul 26 14:17:49 servername sshd[12930]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=91.117.124.14  user=root
Jul 26 14:17:51 servername sshd[12930]: Failed password for root from 91.117.124.14 port 37340 ssh2
Jul 26 14:17:51 servername sshd[12930]: Received disconnect from 91.117.124.14: 11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Jul 26 14:17:51 servername sshd[12932]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=91.117.124.14  user=root
Jul 26 14:17:53 servername sshd[12932]: Failed password for root from 91.117.124.14 port 38980 ssh2
Jul 26 14:17:54 servername sshd[12932]: Received disconnect from 91.117.124.14: 11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Jul 26 14:17:54 servername sshd[12934]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=91.117.124.14  user=root
Jul 26 14:17:56 servername sshd[12934]: Failed password for root from 91.117.124.14 port 40576 ssh2
Jul 26 14:17:56 servername sshd[12934]: Received disconnect from 91.117.124.14: 11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Jul 26 14:17:57 servername sshd[12936]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=91.117.124.14  user=root
Jul 26 14:17:58 servername sshd[12936]: Failed password for root from 91.117.124.14 port 42148 ssh2
Jul 26 14:17:58 servername sshd[12936]: Received disconnect from 91.117.124.14: 11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Jul 26 14:17:59 servername sshd[12938]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=91.117.124.14  user=root
Jul 26 14:18:01 servername CRON[12940]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 26 14:18:01 servername sshd[12938]: Failed password for root from 91.117.124.14 port 43589 ssh2
Jul 26 14:18:01 servername sshd[12938]: Received disconnect from 91.117.124.14: 11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Jul 26 14:18:01 servername CRON[12940]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 26 14:18:01 servername sshd[12982]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=91.117.124.14  user=root
Jul 26 14:18:03 servername sshd[12982]: Failed password for root from 91.117.124.14 port 44989 ssh2
Jul 26 14:18:03 servername sshd[12982]: Received disconnect from 91.117.124.14: 11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Jul 26 14:18:04 servername sshd[12985]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=91.117.124.14  user=root
Jul 26 14:18:06 servername sshd[12985]: Failed password for root from 91.117.124.14 port 46546 ssh2
Jul 26 14:18:06 servername sshd[12985]: Received disconnect from 91.117.124.14: 11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Jul 26 14:18:06 servername sshd[12987]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=91.117.124.14  user=root
Jul 26 14:18:09 servername sshd[12987]: Failed password for root from 91.117.124.14 port 48192 ssh2
Jul 26 14:18:09 servername sshd[12987]: Received disconnect from 91.117.124.14: 11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Jul 26 14:18:09 servername sshd[12989]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=91.117.124.14  user=root
Jul 26 14:18:11 servername sshd[12989]: Failed password for root from 91.117.124.14 port 49739 ssh2
Jul 26 14:18:11 servername sshd[12989]: Received disconnect from 91.117.124.14: 11: Normal Shutdown, Thank you for playing [preauth]
Jul 26 14:18:11 servername sshd[12991]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=91.117.124.14  user=root
Jul 26 14:18:13 servername sshd[12991]: Failed password for root from 91.117.124.14 port 51193 ssh2
```

The login attempts go on for 20 minutes and more and fail2ban doesn't do a thing.

Comment: You should have "Failregex" lines in the `fail2ban-regex /var/log/auth.log.1 /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/sshd.conf` result (on my machine, I do). Just in case, did you restart fail2ban after configuration change?

Comment: Oh sorry, missed those, but they're in there as they should be I think. Edited my question.

Comment: When did you last change your fail2ban config? When did you last restart fail2ban? Do your `/var/log/fail2ban.log*` files show any ban for ssh?

Comment: Last config change was months ago and the server is restarted every now and then for kernel updates. Fail2ban.log doesn't show any bans.

Answer (score 1):

Increase the debugging to help figure out why fail2ban isn't blocking anything when your regexs work with your configured log file.

```
fail2ban-client set loglevel DEBUG
```

In my case, I had a problem similar to yours.  Config checked out okay, jail was running, proper log file, and the regex were all getting high counts when checking with `fail2ban-regex`.  After turning up debugging, the vital clue appeared:

```
2016-02-17 11:27:57,450 fail2ban.datedetector   [30443]: DEBUG   Got time 1455722877.000000 for "u'Feb 17 10:27:57'" using template (?:DAY )?MON Day 24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Year)?
2016-02-17 11:27:57,450 fail2ban.filter         [30443]: DEBUG   Processing line with time:1455722877.0 and ip:8.8.8.8
2016-02-17 11:27:57,450 fail2ban.filter         [30443]: DEBUG   Ignore line since time 1455722877.0 < 1455726477.45 - 600
```

Notice the time difference is outside of the `findtime` (600), and is actually 3600 seconds, or one hour.  Previously, the system time zone had been changed, and the system not rebooted.  The times in syslog were all off one hour from system time.  Restarting rsyslogd then caused new log entries to be written with the correct time, and fail2ban no longer ignored those log entries.

Comment: In my case, it was with an RHEL 7 system. However, the same failure could occur on other distros, and increasing log verbosity will set you down the right path to solving the problem.